# Developing "Action" that shows changed value of form-field using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

for a vector-layer I would like to produce an action, that shows the
changed value in a formular.

E.G. I am editing a vector-point-layer, click on a point, the fomular
is opening. I change a value (lets say 
the formular-field "z" had a value "test" and I change it to "test2").

Then I start my developed action.

I tried for example:

---

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, "Feature id", "feature id is [
$z ] '%Z%' '%z%' $z [z] $Z [Z] [%z%] [%Z%]")
```

---

but I always get the "old" value "test" and not the formular-changed
value "test2".

Has anybody an idea what I can do?

Comment: Did you save your modifications before trigger your action ?

Comment: No, I did not. I try to find a solution where I can find the changed values in the form before they are saved.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Not by an action but by a specific formular:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget,QLineEdit,QPushButton,QDialogButtonBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    control = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "z")
    #layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global myFeature
    myFeature= feature
    buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox,"buttonBox")
    #buttonBox.accepted.disconnect(myDialog.accept)
    #Wire up our own signals.
    buttonBox.accepted.connect(validate)
    #buttonBox.rejected.connect(myDialog.reject)
    # Wire up our own signals.
    #pushButton.accepted.connect(validate)

def validate():

    qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Autosave", u"Validalli : ")
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    #qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Autosave", u"blba : "+z.text())
    z = myDialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "z")
    myFeature['z'] = z.text()
    layer.updateFeature(myFeature)

    layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

If s.o. wants to add a new feature it`s important in ther validate-section:
activeLayer.startEditing()
activeLayer.addFeature(myFeature)

activeLayer.commitChanges()